# Installing FIREFOX with extensions/addons manually? (not really auto install)

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, installer

I've been reading around with regards to creating firefox installers, bundling it w/ addons, using scripts, and CLI lines and a whole bunch of stuffs ... but it seems that going through this route is just too complicated and time consuming..

Since i don't mind a bit of manually copying files and stuff, I was planning to do the following:
on my test machine,

1) install  firefox  on a machine AND configure it the way i want it 
2) install addons AND set the configurations for it 
3) set advanced configurations for firefox (about:config)

Then once i'm all set, I just simply copy the contents of the firefox/profiles folder (for this particular tests it's

....\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\6m0mef0s.default

for deployment, all i have to do is:
1) Install the same version (offline installer) of the Firefox i used.. 
2) overwrite the contents of the new profiles folder (randomly named by Firefox installer as usual) ..

This should set all my configs and addons right?

or what other folders do i have to backup and copy manually into the new profiles folder?
I don't think i need to tinker w/ any registries right?

anyway, if this works, though it's a bit manual, it's a whole lot simplier, and straight forward than fiddling w/ Installers and Packages etc..

PS
I do this a lot w/ other simple (and some complex) software that i use and they seem to work fine for years.. i'm just not sure with firefox and how it's structured..

Comment: http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable

Comment: tnx crazy potato, but i found portable firefox (and other apps) slower to launch vs installed apps.. might be just me but i've noticed this few times already, hence i dont use portables on my main computers only when im on the go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major problem the folder you want is in the AppData/Roaming folder, Local/Mozilla should only store the cache otherwise it will completely work, I've done it at least a couple dozen times.

Couple things that I've learned.

1. The Firefox versions don't appear to need to be the exact same. (But keep it reasonable)
2. The easiest way to move your profile is after you install firefox on the second computer don't open it, move the Mozilla folder from the first computer to the second. You can also edit profile.ini or just overwrite the new with the old.
3. If you set up sync before moving and are still going to use the same profile on multiple machines change the device name on one because it might cause problems.
4. Using a batch script to copy your profile is by far the easiest and most reliable way to backup Firefox.
5. It also works with Thunderbird.

Comment: very valuable advises here mate.. thanks very very much! :)